# Why does @InjectMocks controller's response get turned into empty by Mockito when I use @JsonView?

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito, spring-restcontroller

I am getting an empty json `{}` (verified via `actions.andReturn().getResponse().getContentAsString()`) as a response when I test via `mockMvc.perform(post...))` *despite* the method actually returning a response (I see this when I debug and step through the code. It's a valid, filled response object but suddenly becomes null when some code in mockito is making a modalAndView -why does it do this?).

Test class:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class Test
{
    //Also tried @Mock
    @InjectMocks
    private MyService myService;

    @Mock
    private MyDAO myDAO;

    //@Autowired
    @InjectMocks
    private MyController myController;

    @Before
    public void setup() {

        //Build the controller mock handler
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
            .standaloneSetup(myController)
            .setControllerAdvice(new ExceptionHandler())
            .build();
    }

    @org.junit.Test
    public void testMyEndpoint() throws Exception
    {
        //Make a request object
        MyRequest request = readJson("request.json", MyRequest.class );

        List<MyObject> objects = readJson("data.json", MyObject.class );

        Mockito.when(
            myDAO.getData( request )
        ).thenReturn(objects);

        Mockito.when(
            myService.callDAO(request)
        )
            .thenReturn(objects)

        //Call the aum endpoint
        ResultActions actions = mockMvc.perform(
            post( "/v1/endpoint" )
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .content( new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString( request ) )
        );

        //Why is this empty?
        System.out.println( actions.andReturn().getResponse().getContentAsString() );
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the part of your code where the result gets `null`?

Comment: @SilverNak the results are never null in my code. It's when I debugged and stepped into Mockito's code that it suddenly did that

Comment: So, `actions.andReturn().getResponse().getContentAsString()` does return a value?

Comment: @SilverNak It returns `{}`. But that's not what my actual rest controller returns. It returns a full object with properties set (I see this in debugging).

Comment: @SilverNak I don't know how to solve it but the issue is because my controller method has a `@JsonView` on it! When I remove it, it works! (I have: ` @JsonView(Views.MyView.class)`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mockito uses an ObjectMapper that does not understand `@JsonView`. To get around this you need to set a message converter that does.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class Test
{
    //Also tried @Mock
    @InjectMocks
    private MyService myService;

    @Mock
    private MyDAO myDAO;

    //@Autowired
    @InjectMocks
    private MyController myController;

    /**
     * This is required for JsonViews.
     * @return
     */
    public static MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter createJacksonConverter() {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.configure(MapperFeature.DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION, true);

        MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
        converter.setObjectMapper(objectMapper);
        return converter;
    }

    @Before
    public void setup() {

        //Build the controller mock handler
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
            .standaloneSetup(myController)
            .setControllerAdvice(new ExceptionHandler())
            .setMessageConverters(createJacksonConverter())
            .build();
    }

    @org.junit.Test
    public void testMyEndpoint() throws Exception
    {
        //Make a request object
        MyRequest request = readJson("request.json", MyRequest.class );

        List<MyObject> objects = readJson("data.json", MyObject.class );

        Mockito.when(
            myDAO.getData( request )
        ).thenReturn(objects);

        Mockito.when(
            myService.callDAO(request)
        )
            .thenReturn(objects)

        //Call the aum endpoint
        ResultActions actions = mockMvc.perform(
            post( "/v1/endpoint" )
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .content( new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString( request ) )
        );

        //Why is this empty?
        System.out.println( actions.andReturn().getResponse().getContentAsString() );
    }
}
```